# updating display name in firebase data for signed user not working, doen't update

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I got a call to `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, but then want to update adding a name row to identify this user. Here I'm presenting the sequence:

HTML Component

```
 <form #submitSign='ngForm' (submit)="signUp(submitSign.value)">
   <div class="form-group col-md-12 mx-auto">
      <label for="passwordUser">Name and Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="signUpUser.nameUser" name="nameUser" class="form-control"
        id="nameUser" placeholder="Name and Last Name" #nameUser="ngModel"
        minlength="6" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':nameUser.errors&&nameUser.touched}" required>

    </div>
    <div [hidden]='!nameUser.errors?.required'>Name Required</div>
    <div [hidden]='!nameUser.errors?.minlength'>Name needs at leas 6 characters </div>
  </form>
```

basically this is the input of username with some basic rules for validations as well

MODEL interface from Signup Form

```
export interface signUpForm{
  nameUser?:string,
  emailUser?:string;
  passwordUser?:string;
  confirmPasswordUser?:string;
  imageUser?:string
}
```

Here just the signUp model interface i create to reign validations as well as data user insert in the form including user name

LOGINSERVICE where in is include the signUp section

```
all imports....

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  formSignup: signUpForm = {
    nameUser: '',
    emailUser: '',
    passwordUser: '',
    confirmPasswordUser: '',
    imageUser: '',
  };
  authStateUser: boolean;

  constructor(
    private userLogin: AngularFireAuth,
    private docCreator: AngularFirestore
  ) {}


  signUpUser(emailUser: string, passwordUser: string) {
    return new Promise((response, reject) => {
      this.userLogin
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailUser, passwordUser)
        .then(
          (responseOk) => {
            response(responseOk), (this.userdata.uid = responseOk.user.uid);
            this.userdata.restData = responseOk.user;

             responseOk.user.updateProfile({
              displayName:this.formSignup.nameUser
            })========HERE IS THE CORE oF MY PROBLEM CAUSE DOESN'T UPDATE DISPLAYNAME==========

          },
          (error) => reject(error)
        )
    })
  }
```

Basically in this service i do import all the modules i might need to access firebase auth params as well as firestore(constructor).Initialize a method for SignUp which would be accessed from the component, and also try to update the friebase params updating profile of user adding it a displayName retrieved from the signUpForm model initialized(but doesn't work!!!!).

Here is where issue is!!
SIGNUP component

```
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  defaultImage: string;
  imgSelected: any;

  signUpUser: signUpForm = {
    nameUser:'',
    emailUser: '',
    passwordUser: '',
    confirmPasswordUser: '',
    imageUser: '',
  };

  constructor(
    private signUserUp: LoginService,
    private router: Router,
    private createDoc:AngularFirestore,
    private UserAuth:AngularFireAuth,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  signUp(value: signUpForm) {
    this.signUserUp
      .signUpUser(value.emailUser, value.passwordUser)
      .then((response) => {
        this.router.navigate(['welcome']);
        this.createDoc.collection('users').add(this.signUserUp.userdata.uid)
      })
      .catch((error) => error.messages);
   }
```

then here the sign up component which basically works fine , my problems is trying to update the user displayName from the service .
Any idea about how could i improve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need change promise sequence as follow

```js
      signUpUser(emailUser: string, passwordUser: string) {
        return new Promise((response, reject) => {
          this.userLogin
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailUser, passwordUser)
            .then(
              (responseOk) => {
                this.userdata.uid = responseOk.user.uid;

                this.userdata.restData = responseOk.user;

                responseOk.user.updateProfile({
                  displayName: this.formSignup.nameUser
                })
                .then(() => {
                  console.log('displayname setted');
                  response(responseOk);
                });

              },
              (error) => reject(error)
            )
        })
      }
```

Comment: can i ask you some else?

Comment: i got the display updated, but want to store it in firesore to as data then estabishing the path thrrough my AngularFirestoreModule i reach to that new user created , and then accesing the doc through the method set try to display the new name updated , but doesnt work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61917009/set-in-firestore-the-new-displayname-updated-with-angular

Comment: Hola Radik...sorry for disturb you ..i have little issue iin here and wanted to check with you...good day...!!!https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62002285/how-to-pop-up-a-modal-from-click-in-dropdown-list-option

Answer (score 0):

You can create

> user_name

public variable in service. Then you can use it in component. First you must import you service, then you must create publick object in component constrctor like this:

> constructor(public login_service: LoginService) {}

then you can use service variable in component html like this

> ligin_service.user_name